# Multiple curved Text on circle -the impossible request-

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know what the designer was thinking, but am sure it wasn't the developer!

**The problem:**
The circle works like tabs, i.e. If you click on the **green** section you get a text and if you click on the **teal** text you get another one accordingly. The text can be changed from the CMS, so I can't simply put an image. The circle also has to be animated, but lets put this problem on hold.

The design I have is this:

[image]

I tried to do something with [this library](http://letteringjs.com/) here, but all I did was manage to write **red** **green** and **teal** text on the right place, with some responsivness (its not great).

I can't even begin to think of a solution to address all the problems of this design. Even if I managed to do the text, I wont be able to do the 6 sections (colored red to teal).
Is there a different way to do this other than CSS/javascript? It seems impossible!

Comment: Looks like an ideal situation for an SVG.

Comment: use svg to create complex shapes. With svg you could also write a text along a curved path

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Do you recommend a place to start understanding svg??

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/default.asp - You can begin here. And there is also a canvas tutorial.